# Extjs4 Formatting date column in GridPanel

Tags: extjs, grid, date-format

Normally it works like this:

```
{
   text:'title1',
   dataIndex: 'dataIndex1',
   renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('d/m/Y')
},
```

But in the renderer I have a function. Like this:

```
{
                text:'title1',
                dataIndex: 'dataIndex1',
                renderer: function(value, p, r)
                {
                    my_store.clearFilter(true);
                    var index = my_store.findExact('cin',r.get('cin'));
                    var rec = my_store.getAt(index);
                    if(rec!=null)
                    {
                        return rec.get('dataIndex1')
                    }
                }
            }
```

So how to add `Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('d/m/Y')` to the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value will be what renderer return.

So, if dataIndex1 is the value containing the date to Format, here is the function that should do it:

```
function(value, p, r) {
    var result = 0;
    my_store.clearFilter(true);
    var index = my_store.findExact('cin', r.get('cin'));
    var rec = my_store.getAt(index);
    if (rec != null) {
        result = rec.get('dataIndex1');
        return Ext.util.Format.date(result, 'm/d/Y');
    }
}
```